# f vectors of simplicial complexes homeomorphic to n dimensional spheres

Tags: co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

In dimension 2, the euler poincare formula restricts the incidence properties of  edges in a triangulation of a surface. 
Are there analogous generalizations for higher dimensions, like elaborations on the Schenzel formula for the specific case pf spheres?

Comment: For a triangulated manifold of dimension $d > 0$, the $(d-1)$-dimensional simplices must all have exactly two $d$-dimensional co-faces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $g$-conjecture (or $g$-theorem in the polytopal case) aims the characterize what possible $f$-vectors can arise from simplicial spheres. [Here](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/how-the-g-conjecture-came-about/) is some nice history and introduction to the $g$-conjecture by Gil Kalai. In brief the $g$-conjecture says that for a simplicial sphere the $h$-vector should be symmetric and the $g$-vector should be an $M$-vector where $g_i = h_i - h_{i-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

As is alluded to in the [article linked in the previous answer](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/how-the-g-conjecture-came-about/), the Dehn-Sommerville equations are a powerful generalization of the Euler-Poincare formula for a homology sphere.  These say that, for a homology $d$-sphere, the relation $h_i = h_{d-i}$ holds for every $i \in {0,\dots, d}$.  This simple $h$-vector relation can be expanded out into a rather more complicated (but equivalent) relation on the $f$-vector.  In particular, the relation $h_d = h_0$ recovers the Euler-Poincare formula.

There's a nice [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn%E2%80%93Sommerville_equations) on the Dehn-Sommerville equations.  In particular, you can look here if you want to see the $f$-vector formulation of the equations.

The Wikipedia article only mentions simplicial polytopes.  If you want a reference for the statement on homology spheres, see the Kalai article (informally), or, in somewhat different language, Stanley's book *Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra*.